# Uniform continuity proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I wrote a proof. Can someone please verify it? I have no idea what I just wrote.

> Suppose $f$ is a real-valued function continuous on $[a, b]$. Show that the function defined by $f^*(x) = $ sup$\{f(y):y \in [a,x]\}$ is continuous.

Note that $f^*$ is increasing. To see this, suppose $x_1, x_2 \in [a,b]$, with $x_1 < x_2$.

Then, $\{f(y):y \in [a,x_1]\} \subseteq \{f(y):y \in [a,x_2]\}$.

Therefore, sup $\{f(y):y \in [a,x_1]\} \leq$ sup $\{f(y):y \in [a,x_2]\}$.

That is, $f^*(x_1) \leq f^*(x_2)$

Now, since $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x_2-x_1| < \delta \implies |f(x_2)-f(x_1)| < \epsilon$. We can assume, with loss of generality, that $x_1 < x_2$.

Now, let $\alpha = $ sup$\{f(y):y \in [a,x_2]\}$ and $\beta =$ sup $\{f(y):y \in [a,x_1]\}$. Since $f$ is continuous on a closed interval $[a,b]$, it must be the case that $\alpha \in \{f(y):y \in [a,x_2]\}$ and $\beta \in \{f(y):y \in [a,x_1]\}$.

If $\alpha \in \{f(y):y \in [a,x_1]\}$, then it must be the case that $\alpha = \beta$. That is, $|f^*(x_2) - f^*(x_1)| = 0$.

Now, suppose that $\alpha > \beta$. Then, it must be the case that $\alpha \in \{f(y):y \in [x_1,x_2]\}$. That is, $f(x_3) = \alpha$ for some $x_3 \in [x_1, x_2]$. Also, $\beta \geq f(y)$ for every $y \in [a, x_1]$. In particular, $f(x_3) > \beta \geq f(x_1)$. By the intermediate value theorem, $\exists x_4 \in [x_1, x_3]$ such that $f(x_4) = \beta$.

Therefore, $|f^*(x_2) - f^*(x_1)| = |f(x_3) - f(x_4)| < \epsilon$

Comment: --I have no idea what I just wrote.-- What exactly do you mean by this????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. However, You can shorten your argument somewhat by noting that your ideas also imply that
$$
α=\max\left(β, \sup_{x\in[x_1,x_2]}f(x)\right)
$$
and that for $x\in[x_1,x_2]$, because of $|x_2-x_1|<δ$,
$$
f(x_1)-ϵ<f(x)<f(x_1)+ϵ
\implies
f(x_1)-ϵ\le\sup_{x\in[x_1,x_2]}f(x)\le f(x_1)+ϵ
$$
and thus with $f(x_1)\le β$,
$$
β\le α\le\max(β,f(x_1)+ϵ)\le β+ϵ
$$